# C# Windows phone visible more objects

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013.

I'm making a Universal application for Windows Phone 8.1.

After TextBlock value become grater or equal then 22, some images should become visible. If the value is less then 22 all images should be invisible.

This is some examples which I tried:

```
private void points_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    int n = 0;
    bool b = int.TryParse(points.Text, out n);

    if (b && n <= 22)
    {
        hole10img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole11img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole12img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole13img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole14img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole15img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole16img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole17img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        hole18img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

[My test sample](http://failiem.lv/u/pkknsfc#)

After i start app, cant see more hole image while textblock value become grater or equal 22.
but after user gets 22 holes images(From hole 10 to hole 18) doesn't' become visible :O
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're not reacting to any event when `points.Text` changes.
You should subscribe to that event and perform the check again. If your condition is met, you can enable the elements' visibility.

Note: you should definitely use the **MVVM** pattern provided from the Microsoft platform, with a good starting framework such as [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/)

This kind of UI update will not be sustainable once your application will grow.